# Looping the rows incrementing by 3 PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some difficulties to take the columns from database incremented by 3.

I have some columns in my table : `1 2 3`

The columns are automatically incremented when user submits information.
So the second columns for the second data will be: `4 5 6`

I make the table headings this way:

```
<?php

$a=1;
while ($a <= $FinalLoopColumns) {

    echo "<th>".'CustomerName'.$a."</th>";
    echo "<th>".'Pieces'.$a."</th>";
    echo "<th>".'Date'.$a."</th>";

    $a++;
}  

?>
```

So I need to insert data to "**CustomerName**" *1* and *4*,  **Pieces** *2* and *5* and **Date** *3* and *6*.

If I had to show my numbers from and array I would do it this way for the CustomerName:

```
$CustomerName=array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($Musteri); $i+=3) {
    echo $CustomerName[$i];
}
```

So I assume I need to take the columns as array and then loop them to find the numbers for each value.

What is the best way to take the data this way from the database and inserting it to the table with while loop using array ? (or doing in another way)

Thanks !

Comment: This seems like a faulty database design.  Not sure why you wouldn't have proper column associations.

Comment: I have no idea how you table looks like but it should be one row = one data and one column = one field I think